# Short Story about a boy and a dog, where all animals can talk

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There was this short story I read a few years back that I would really like to find. It's title was something like "democracy" or "democrazy".

The summary of what I remember:

There is this boy and a dog. I think there is another animal with them as well. All the animals and this boy can talk to each other because they are all equal. Because of the "democrazy." At one point they are hungry and kill and eat at cat while the cat says that he is too fat and has a family to feed. They eat him anyway. There is also a scene where the boy and the dog (female) have sex. The other animal that is with them says that it is wrong and that "democrazy" has gone too far. Another pack of dogs attack and bite the female dog. She gets what seems to be rabies, though there is another name for it in the story.
They then attack a human compound of some sort because the dog is dying and she wants the boy to be safe. I think that she crashes a car into a wall so she can get him in because she is going to die from the rabies anyways.

It was a really strange story and I am trying to find it just to prove it exists. Some people claim I made it up... I'm not that imaginative. Can anyone help me?

Another thing that might help is that it was in an anthology of some sort that began with the letter N or M (that was where it was in the fiction section of the library I read it in)

Added (remembered or suggested later): Cats were not as smart, the setting was a apocalyptic future where humanity was almost wiped out. (thanks HugoRune!)

Comment: I remember reading this story. One other point was that cats were not as smart as other animals, or slower to convert to sentience, because of their cleanliness, suggesting the thing making them intelligent was a plague or airborne pollutant. Unfortunately I cannot remember much more. I read it in German, at least 15 years ago. It contained some made up portmanteaux, like "sexualitäter", a combination of 'sex' and 'culprit'. Can you remember those portmanteaux in English?

Comment: I think the setting was some sort of post-apocalyptic future, with civilization and most of humanity wiped out due to some war, and the animals just coming to terms with their sentience.

Comment: I've read it, too, but danged if I can remember where. It's not in Ellen Datlow's two "Alien Sex" anthologies, I just checked.

Comment: It was an anthology, not a collection by one author. And yes the library was organized alphabetically by author.

Comment: I do remember the made up word, I think the "democrazy" was one of them. And it is a very memorable story when you read it.

Comment: Any of these authors ring a bell: K.W. Jeter, Philip José Farmer, Connie Willis, Samuel R. Delany, ?

Comment: The "democrazy" word makes me think it's an older work - 60's or 70's, maybe.

Comment: I have this story somewhere but don't know where. Varley, maybe?

Comment: I read it in Analog or Asimovs, late 80s or early 90s.  I particularly remember the phrase "because they violented democrazy".  Yup, here's a [snippet view](http://books.google.com/books?id=tRArAQAAIAAJ&q=%22violented+democrazy%22).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The Coon Rolled Down and Ruptured his Larinks, a Squeezed Novel by Mr. Skunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Coon_Rolled_Down_and_Ruptured_His_Larinks,_A_Squeezed_Novel_by_Mr._Skunk). 
By Dafydd ab Hugh, 1990.  Nominated in 1991 for both the Hugo Award for Best Novelette and the Nebula Award for Best Novelette.

> "*The story is set in a post-apocalyptic world where all animals have
>   acquired human-level intelligence and the ability to speak -- and all
>   humans have become mentally retarded.*"

The anthology you read it in was probably Nebula Awards 26.

Chapter 5 is titled; "We meet death and **democrazy**"

Comment: Readable [here](http://www.docin.com/p-603504491.html), though probably not legally.