# Old sci fi story where all Earth's animals are at war with mankind

Tags: story-identification, books

Very vague on the details here, sorry.

UK novelette or thin paperback book I read about 1971 or 1972, but it could have been older.

I think an alien spaceship had somehow had an accident or was shot down by mistake.  In its final moments (again I think) it sent out an Earth-wide revenge broadcast and this caused the problems.

All animals and birds rose up against humanity but their intelligence was boosted so, for example, there were troops of chimpanzees using artillery (see what I did there? Troops!) and various flocks of birds attacking soldiers, etc. worldwide.

Due to numbers I think the animals prevailed at first so mankind had to get really 'top of the food chain' down-and-dirty to fight back.

Edit: Another small bit I've just remembered, some humans are hiding in a ditch near some gorillas who are firing captured artillery. One man starts near choking with suppressed laughter as he watches them loading 'wrong size' and then they attempt to fire a salvo.

Kaboom!  Half a dozen exploded heavy guns and loads of dead and injured apes.
I think there were more incidents like that so realisation dawns that the guiding intelligence is flawed.

Comment: My first impulse is to suggest _[Deathworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld)_ by Harry Harrison.

Comment: No, I've got the Deathworld books, this, as stated in my question, is an Earth wide thing. Thanks for responding

Comment: Yeah, first impulses generally make better comments than answers.

Comment: Not a perfect match, but Brain Wave by Poul Anderson?

Comment: No its not Brain Wave, that had the animals getting intelligence yeah, but, in the story I'm after, is was more like organised aggression against people

Comment: I keep reading "old omelette", and it's not I didn't have breakfast yet.

Comment: @motoDrizzt I fixed the title for you!

Comment: No help from TV Tropes:  https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UpliftedAnimal

Comment: @Ayshe Having just now read the question, I was about to post a comment saying I was nearly certain it was **not** Poul Anderson's novel *Brain Wave,* despite a similar premise -- but I see you already raised the possibility, and DannyMcG already dismissed it.

Comment: Could you mean [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60113/16171) ?

Comment: Nah sorry, I read this one while still at school so published no later than 1972